# Seeking USB-to-USB Emulation Software for Keyboard and Mouse Input During Boot Process (Windows)

Tags: windows, keyboard, emulator, mouse

I am hoping someone in this knowledgeable community might have a solution for a unique problem I’m facing. I’m trying to control a desktop PC using my laptop’s keyboard and mouse via a USB-to-USB connection (Windows). The goal is for the desktop to perceive my laptop’s input devices as if they were directly connected to it through USB.

This particular requirement is due to the necessity to send keyboard inputs during the PC’s boot process. While I am aware of solutions such as Mouse Without Borders, these tools, as great as they are, hinge on having a network connection and both computers to be completely booted and running the software. This wouldn’t meet my requirements as I need to be able to interact with my PC before it fully boots up.

If anyone has encountered similar scenarios or knows of any software or method that could accomplish this, I would greatly appreciate your advice. Looking forward to hearing from you and thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please delete your identical question on superuser

Comment: The core need is same as a KVM switch which as hardware will control the remote device from a common keyboard/mouse/monitor thus to "emulate" afar you need a physical endpoint now using a live slave device at the far end of comms could provide that hardwire support but you need that physical clone to be afar. During boot up the hardwired keyboard then mouse will be queried before network ability 
 (hmm I wonder about WOL signals ? perhaps that already booted) so the only normal way is a split in far end comms with a mechanical interface to the target perhaps a $4 Raspberry Pi or similar.

Comment: Windows (from my knowledge) lacks an easy way to emulate a USB slave, I've decided to leverage the ATmega32U4 with the Arduino IDE. This allows keyboard and mouse emulation via a locally hosted server, as if connected directly via USB to the target. Beyond that, it permits a clipboard function, creating a KVM solution minus video. So, despite limitations, this approach makes sense for my project.

Comment: Sticking with the software only solution, I am wondering if there is a way to emulate a USB slave, if there is, let me know. Another solution I had that is a software only solution is possible by hosting a local server, and passing through the HID devices, as if they were directly plugged into USB by routing their inputs through the server and then passing them through the USB cable. Maybe in this way, the USB only acts as a middleman/mediator for the HID devices and the target. Do you let me know what you think of the software only base solutions? Thank you for your response I appreciate you.

Comment: The PiKVM is a hardware solution that does what you want.  The only software USB emulation requires a booted system.  You might be able to emulate the keyboard & mouse on a Pi or other SBC, but you won't see the screen unless you attach a video capture device to the video card.  Which is partially what the PiKVM does.